# SRCSRV: Source server cannot retrieve the source code for file

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, symbol-server, srcsrv

In the company I work for, we're using source server to fetch the proper source from the svn repository that corresponds to the app version that generated a crash dump file.
After recent windows updates (unsure if related, but happens on all machines with win7 and win10), the symbol server fails to download the files with the following error:

```
SRCSRV:  cmd /c svn.exe cat "https://MY-URL-HERE/source/somefile.cpp@30365" --non-interactive > "C:\MY-LOCAL-PATH-HERE\source\somefile.cpp\30365\somefile.cpp" && attrib +R "C:\MY-LOCAL-PATH-HERE\source\somefile.cpp\30365\somefile.cpp"
SRCSRV: Source server cannot retrieve the source code for file 'd:\jenkins\workspace\SOME-PATH\somefile.cpp' in module 'C:\SOME-ANOTHER-PATH\SymbolCache\myapp.exe\5a7b888e14d9000\myapp.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've hunted down that the problem is, that the specified path doesn't exist:

```
C:\MY-LOCAL-PATH-HERE\source\somefile.cpp\30365\
```

In the past, the symbol server managed somehow to automatically create all necessary folders, but not anymore.
If I create the path manually myself, all works fine!

I've tried playing around with various debug options in msvc IDE, but after spending a few hours googling around for answers, none worked for me.
All I've found that it's possible to disable specific system commands in the srcsrv.ini file, but I'm not sure how to tell the srcsrv that you're allowed to create folders for me?

I set the devenv of MSVC to always run as administrator. Did the same with svn.exe.

Here are screenshots from my debug settings:
[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahK2J.jpg)
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyvzc.jpg)

It can't be that I must create all folders manually every time I want to debug a dump file :(

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to parent folder permissions. Try to start the debugger as administrator or check your permissions on C:\MY-LOCAL-PATH-HERE\